# Scala: How to map a subset of a seq to a shorter seq

Tags: scala

I am trying to map a subset of a sequence using another (shorter) sequence while preserving the elements that are not in the subset. A toy example below tries to give a flower to females only:

```
def giveFemalesFlowers(people: Seq[Person], flowers: Seq[Flower]): Seq[Person] = {
  require(people.count(_.isFemale) == flowers.length)
  magic(people, flowers)(_.isFemale)((p, f) => p.withFlower(f))
}

def magic(people: Seq[Person], flowers: Seq[Flower])(predicate: Person => Boolean)
         (mapping: (Person, Flower) => Person): Seq[Person] = ???
```

Is there an elegant way to implement the magic?

Comment: `magic` has no access to `Flower` - need to pass it to it in some way

Comment: Thank you Aleksey, edited the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an iterator over `flowers`, *consume* one each time the `predicate` holds; the code would look like this,

```
val it = flowers.iterator
people.map ( p => if (predicate(p)) p.withFlowers(it.next) else p )
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: Might be worth noting that this is bad practice as it mixes mutable state and functional programming.

Comment: @Felix, you are right, but the closest functional solution is Shadowlands's below, which one do you prefer?

Comment: Well that's not entirely true. I have both a recursive solution in my answer below AND a very concise solution (which doesn't preserver the ordering) using partition and zip. 
The above won't work in parallel and you must be careful not to leak the iterator.

Answer (score 0):

What about zip (aka zipWith) ?

```
scala> val people = List("m","m","m","f","f","m","f")
people: List[String] = List(m, m, m, f, f, m, f)

scala> val flowers = List("f1","f2","f3")
flowers: List[String] = List(f1, f2, f3)

scala> def comb(xs:List[String],ys:List[String]):List[String] = (xs,ys) match {
     |  case (x :: xs, y :: ys) if x=="f" => (x+y) :: comb(xs,ys)
     |  case (x :: xs,ys) => x :: comb(xs,ys)
     |  case (Nil,Nil) => Nil
     | }

scala> comb(people, flowers)
res1: List[String] = List(m, m, m, ff1, ff2, m, ff3)
```

If the order is not important, you can get this elegant code:

```
scala> val (men,women) = people.partition(_=="m")
men: List[String] = List(m, m, m, m)
women: List[String] = List(f, f, f)

scala> men ++ (women,flowers).zipped.map(_+_)
res2: List[String] = List(m, m, m, m, ff1, ff2, ff3)
```

Comment: No, as I said I have to preserve the males in the output, so mere filtering doesn't work

Comment: I corrected my answer. I don't believe the standard library has anything for this because it is oddly specific. Is the order of the output important?

Comment: The first solution works, unfortunately not tail-recursive. The second one is not applicable - these are Seqs for a reason (not Sets).

Answer (score 0):

I am going to presume you want to retain all the starting people (not simply filter out the females and lose the males), and in the original order, too.

Hmm, bit ugly, but what I came up with was:

```
def giveFemalesFlowers(people: Seq[Person], flowers: Seq[Flower]): Seq[Person] = {
    require(people.count(_.isFemale) == flowers.length)
    people.foldLeft((List[Person]() -> flowers)){ (acc, p) => p match {
        case pp: Person if pp.isFemale => ( (pp.withFlower(acc._2.head) :: acc._1) -> acc._2.tail)
        case pp: Person => ( (pp :: acc._1) -> acc._2)
    } }._1.reverse
}
```

Basically, a fold-left, initialising the 'accumulator' with a pair made up of an empty list of people and the full list of flowers, then cycling through the people passed in.

If the current person is female, pass it the head of the current list of flowers (field 2 of the 'accumulator'), then set the updated accumulator to be the updated person prepended to the (growing) list of processed people, and the tail of the (shrinking) list of flowers.

If male, just prepend to the list of processed people, leaving the flowers unchanged.

By the end of the fold, field 2 of the 'accumulator' (the flowers) should be an empty list, while field one holds all the people (with any females having each received their own flower), in reverse order, so finish with `._1.reverse`

**Edit**: attempt to clarify the code (and substitute a test more akin to @elm's to replace the `match`, too) - hope that makes it clearer what is going on, @Felix! (and no, no offence taken):

```
def giveFemalesFlowers(people: Seq[Person], flowers: Seq[Flower]): Seq[Person] = {

    require(people.count(_.isFemale) == flowers.length)

    val start: (List[Person], Seq[Flower]) = (List[Person](), flowers)

    val result: (List[Person], Seq[Flower]) = people.foldLeft(start){ (acc, p) =>
        val (pList, fList) = acc
        if (p.isFemale) {
          (p.withFlower(fList.head) :: pList, fList.tail)
        } else {
          (p :: pList, fList)
        }
    }

    result._1.reverse
}
```

Comment: My eyes >.< Could you maybe clean up the code a bit to make it readable? (no offence meant!)

Comment: Works but not elegant, see the selected solution.

Comment: Yeah, it occurred to me later that I could simplify with something similar to @elm (although I still wasn't thinking of something quite as elegant).

Comment: Um, any reason for the swath of down votes? How is this answer "not useful"? Let alone the accepted answer!

Comment: @Felix - edited my answer to (hopefully) show a clearer, simpler version of the code :)

Answer (score -1):

I'm obviously missing something but isn't it just

```
people map {
  case p if p.isFemale => p.withFlower(f)
  case p => p
}
```

Comment: Or, if only the females should be in the result `people collect { case p if p.isFemale => p.withFlower(f) }`

Comment: Every female gehts a separate flower

Comment: As SF said - every female needs to get a different flower from the flowers seq